# vSphere/vCenter not offering SSO options

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, single-sign-on

We started setting up a vSphere infrastructure and want to use OpenLDAP as authentication source.
In the vCenter, we have enabled the embedded SSO server and I find options to connect to Active Directory.

In many places in the Internet, I find descriptions to navigate to **Administration > Sign-on and Discovery > Configuration**, which is however not available in our vSphere installation (`win3011` is the vCenter):

[image]

How can I make the SSO settings available, in order to add a new Identity Source as described e.g. [in this article](http://blog.clearpathsg.com/blog/bid/265188/Configuring-vCenter-SSO-to-Use-a-New-AD-Identity-Source)?

Comment: Which account are you logged in as in the screengrab above?

Comment: I'm logged in as `root`.

Comment: No, sorry, I meant into the vCenter - have you tried the one you're supposed to start with (administrator@vsphere.local)?

Comment: Ah.. man.. thanks! I noticed that when logged in as `administrator@vsphere.local`, this tiny difference pops up!
Would you briefly formulate this as an answer? You earn some credits.
(I interpreted that the `administrator@system-domain` only applies to Windows-based vCenter servers, which seems not the case)

Comment: No, it's for both and ewwhite's already answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in as administrator@vsphere.local

That will produce the desired output.